# html5 caputre camera on iphone not working

Tags: android, ios, iphone, html

I'm using this [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) on the browser to open the camera only and directly without the access to the gallery to take a picture only and the user can't choose from the gallery

```
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="camera" class="form-control"/>
```

and this code work on all android phone but the problem is on the iPhone iOS system the gallery appear to choose image and that what i don't want i want only access to the camera to take a picture.

I try to change the browser from safari to chrome but it didn't work.
I check the version of the ios it's 9.3.5 and also don't work.

What should I to solve this problem on ios and the code work on android and ois together

Comment: On which browser did you test?

Comment: @Fralec safari and chrome on the ios on the android work on all browser chrome and other

Comment: any help please ??!!!